# How can i set height of my banner and vertically align its content to center?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a banner on my webpage, the part on the top that is 700px wide and 80px high.

Code looks like:

```
      <div class="container-narrow" style="heigth: 80px;">

        <img src="#" width="52" height="52" alt="my logo"  />

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
```

Css:

```
    .container-narrow
    {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 700px;
      background: yellow;
    }

    ul
    {
      float: right;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    a
    {
      float: right;
      width: 6em;
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
    }

    a:hover {color: #ccc; text-decoration: none;}

    li {display: inline;}
```

What I want is the image and the horizontal menu to be vertically aligned in the center of the 80px. the logo to the left and the menu to the right.

I've tried to set the height and then padd/margin my way to get the job done but it feels rubbish...

Comment: vertically? or do you mean horizontally by saying "to the left, to the right"? ;>

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use margin to put it correctly, that's what they do, especially when you're working with fixed design (80px height for banner and 52px for image so 28px white space is margin top of 14px...)

Comment: Do you want something like this?? http://jsfiddle.net/uKWM4/

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

`ul` has a `width:100%;` if you give it a black border you will see that its occupying the width of the page, means it has no space to reside on the left of the logo inside the yellow header.

Removing this width will give the following result: http://jsfiddle.net/YBVe6/

Now since the header has a fixed max width, which is 700px, there's many ways to center the logo and the menu.

Fastest way I can think of is the following:

Give `ul` a `display: inline-block;`, (remove `float: right;`) then give the header a `text-align: center;`, here's the result : http://jsfiddle.net/YBVe6/1/

And if you want the menu to be displayed in the upper part, just add `vertical-align: top;`.

Answer (score 0):

To start of, it's a good practice if you have an external CSS, don't put additional CSS in your HTML blocks:

```
<div class="container-narrow">
```

and put the height style in your css sheet, as you have a class setup for your div there anyway.

Second, making typo's is a pain if you want your CSS to work properly, so instead of `heigth` you should use `height`, will make you div actually 80px high.

Third of all: margins are there the position elements. Use them!

```
.container-narrow
    {
        height: 80px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 700px;
        background: yellow;
    }
img
    {
        margin-top:14px;
    }

ul
    {
        float: right;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-top:25px;
    }

a
    {
        width: 6em;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
    }

a:hover {color: #ccc; text-decoration: none;}

li {display: inline;}
```

**Edit**

This is mostly applicable for vertical alignment. If you want to auto-center horizontally, you can make use of the `margin:auto` concept. This is possible because a page can't extend beyond the browser width (browser height can extend as you have scrolling available as default behavior).